# Google oAuth with Phonegap

Tags: cordova, oauth-2.0

I am making an App using Phonegap build and I want my users to be authenticated with their google accounts using oAuth.

I tried following [this](http://www.itsalif.info/content/oauth-google-api-gapi-phonegap-childbrowser-jquery) tutorial but I didn'tget anywhere.

I just need some light on how to do it.

thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show some of the code you've written that you're having problems with?

Comment: @WallyAltman

I basically have the same code the guy does in the tutorial. The weird thing is, if i download his sample app, everything seems to work fine. But if i download his exact code, and don't change anything and then deploy it to phonegap, it doesn't seem to do a thing.

Answer (score 0):

I think the trouble is that Google's OAuth tries to open a new window, but in PhoneGap you have to use the "[ChildBrowser](https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/2)" plugin.